# Are there any infographic what SSL/TLS versions support every OS X?

Tags: macos, ssl, tls1.2

I've been working on adding TLS 1.2 support functionality for OS X application.

I didn't find any clear info what Mac OS X versions support TLS 1.2.

Comment: Apple's docs; https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/secureTransportRef/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find the information at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Libraries). Note that there are several TLS stacks and the supported versions depend also on the TLS stack you use.

The default stack shipped with Mac OS X is Secure Transport which support up to TLS 1.2 (depending on the OS version). But Python, Perl, Ruby... etc use OpenSSL and Apple shipped only the very old OpenSSL version 0.9.8 which only supported up to TLS 1.0. But of course somebody might have installed a newer OpenSSL version to change this.